# Parsing Decimals to significant figures in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml

Have `([Name-Width]*.0393701).toFixed(4);` so far

The [Name-Width] pulls a hsize from a XML XPath then converts that value from millimeters to inches to the fourth decimal point.

Now I need to get a result that makes it looks nice.

Examples:

```
5.1250 = 5.125

5.0625 = 5.0625

5.2500 = 5.25

5.0000 = 5

5.5000 = 5.5
```

Hope you guys can help.

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/3613112/597419

Comment: Hi again Guys. I'm a complete virgin to JavaScript. I need to know what to copy and paste into my existing code. Below what I already have. My brain is already fired :)

Answer (score 2):

Try converting it to string! That won't show any extra zeros!

```
var one = 5.1250;
one.toString();
```

(one = 5.125)

Hope this helps

EDIT: Assigning it to a new var would be better practice

```
var one = 5.1250;
var one_nozeros = one.toString();
```

EDIT: Try this for XML?

```
var one = (<r><![CDATA[

The text string goes here.  Since this is a XML CDATA section,
stuff like <> work fine too, even if definitely invalid XML. 

]]></r>).toString();
```

Comment: Hi again Guys. I'm a complete virgin to JavaScript. I need to know what to copy and paste into my existing code. Below what I already have. My brain is already fired :)

Comment: I still don't understand? My results from the first line of my script always gives me different results from the XML file I'm choosing. Please be patient w/ me

Comment: var inches = ([Name-Width]*.0393701).toFixed(4);
var inches_nz = inches.toString()  Returned No RESULTS

Comment: Now I'm completely lost...