# Why does multiplying by some numbers sometimes return a slightly larger number?

Tags: javascript, floating-point

When I do, for example, 14 * 0.2, I get 2.8000000000000003 instead of 2.8.
Why does it do this, and how can I fix it?

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612744/javascript-remove-insignificant-trailing-zeros-from-a-number) page, Strings automatically cut trailing 0s off, so I tried

```
var foo = 14 * 0.2;
console.log(foo.toFixed(3).toString());
```

but it still comes back with trailing 0s (2.800).

Comment: this is not an error, it is how floating point math works.  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken.  Also, `toString()` doesn't truncate, it strips insignificant 0s (trailing 0s that run to infinity, which this number does not do).

Comment: This is like asking why `0.1 + 0.2` isn't `0.3`.

Comment: Sorry for posting a duplicate post, I couldn't find anything related to my problem in the related posts and didn't know the exact terminology to find the answer on my own. Thanks to everyone for their help, and I don't mind getting down-voted if I come out smarter in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `String` will cut trailing `0s`, But if you will convert that in number then it will ignore trailing `0s` after decimal point.

```
var foo = 14 * 0.2;
console.log(+foo.toFixed(3));
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to the + operator. I now have another useful tool in my belt of knowledge!

Comment: @JosephWebber - Here's more "shortcuts" for you: `num|0` is (almost) the same as `Math.floor` and `num+""` is the same as `num.toString()`.

Comment: They're neat to know but please don't use those kind of shortcuts unless you're code golfing.

Answer (score 0):

Your call of `toFixed` function will return the `String`, not a some kind of a number. And this `String` representation is specifically mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) to have trailing zeros. The next call to `toString` simply does nothing.