# JavaScript dynamic typing int/float

Tags: javascript, dynamic-typing

Is the following correct?  And why?

```
x = 7;
y = 7.00;
z = x + y;
console.log(z);
```

Result:

14

I expect the log result to be "14.00".

Comment: already answered really so have a looky here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612744/javascript-remove-insignificant-trailing-zeros-from-a-number

Comment: Javascript doesn't actually have an "int" type:   all numbers are floats.    For currency, you might want to use something like `z.toFixed(2)` for display purposes.

Comment: @Curt: Actually, for currency, it would be best to do all calculation in integral values, then divide by `100` when displaying (when, yes, you'd display them just as you show); as decimal values are imprecise. Even if the integral values are stored as floats, they are precise up to `9007199254740991`, unlike decimal numbers, which cannot be precise due to how floats function.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, EasyBB.

Comment: @Amadan.   I'm not sure you understood what I was saying.    There is no  "integral" type in Javascript:  there is only numeric, which is floating point.  I'm not suggesting that Scotty use floats--he has no choice.

Comment: @Curt: No, apparently you don't understand what I am saying. I just said there is no integral *type* in my post; but there are certainly integral *values*. If you want to store `7.23`, store `723` instead, and remember that it is two digits off; i.e. do everything in cents. Why? Because `7.23` part cannot be correctly represented in IEEE754, while `723` can. When you need to display, dividing by `100` will be close enough that the display is correct. But if you do calculations on `7.23`, you will eventually end up with the `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.30000000000000004` "bug" (only worse the more you do).

Answer (score 5):

A 99% true statement: There is no "dynamic typing int/float" in JavaScript because there are no ints or floats in JavaScript. `console.log` will write the most compact representation. In fact, `console.log(7.00)` displays `7`.

The more correct statement: integers are internally available in JavaScript (as result of bit-operations, mostly), but all numbers that reach your program are floats.

Finally, there is no reason why `console.log` should display anything to two decimals, unless the most compact representation had two decimals (like `7.23`).

Comment: If instead of the console.log() call I do this in my Chrome console: