# How can I format numbers in a specific way?

Tags: javascript, number-formatting

I want to format my numbers and I want these results.

I have tried `.toFixed(2)` but it didn’t yield the expected results.

```
Input     Result
50.000 => 50
50.900 => 50.9
50.940 => 50.94
50.941 => 50.94
```

Something like `0.##` as formatting but in JavaScript.

Comment: I think you're looking for something like this parseFloat(Math.round(num3 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2); which is explained in this post -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134039/format-number-to-always-show-2-decimal-places

Comment: @robert No the reverse of that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: remove insignificant trailing zeros from a number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612744/javascript-remove-insignificant-trailing-zeros-from-a-number)

Comment: `parseFloat(num.toFixed(2))` will do the trick

Comment: @m90 yes you are right ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function decimalFunction() {
  console.log('click');
  var myvalue = document.getElementById('myInput').value;
  var decimal = Math.round(myvalue * 100) / 100
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML  = decimal;
}
```

```html
<input id="myInput" type="text"/>
<button onclick="decimalFunction()">Submit</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

```
Math.round(inputNumber * 100) / 100
```

Input:
50.000,
50.900,
50.940,
50.941

Output:
50,
50.9,
50.94,
50.94

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use

```
parseFloat(num.toFixed(2));
```

to

- have a maximum of two trailing digits
- omit any superfluous trailing zeros

Comment: your answer is also correct, sorry but I cannot flag two answer as right answer, only +1 :(

Answer (score 0):

change you number to string. After some string operations you can get correct result

```
<script language="Javascript">
    var data = 50.947;
    var res = data.toString().substring(0, data.toString().indexOf('.') + 3);
    alert(res);
</script>
```