# I want to remove the zeros if put in 100 show every numbers from 1 to 100 without zero ex 20 become 2 and 100 become 1

Tags: javascript

I want to remove the zeros,
I like to this model if i put in 1000 Then extra sheet shown all number from 1 to 1000 with every number check and remove the zeros.

Example :if I take in 10 
then output like 1 2 3 .....8 9 1(the 10 remove the zero,and balance 1 is shown).

If I take in 500 then 
like 1 2 ......8 9 1 11 12 13.....19 2 21 22 23 .....29 3 31 32..
98 99 1 11 12 13(101 102 103 remove the zeros) 488 499 5 (500 remove the zeros)

another example is if i take in 1000 then output like
1 2 ......8 9 1 11 12 13.....19 2 21 22 23 .....29 3 31 32..
98 99 1 11 12 13(101 102 103 remove the zeros) 488 499 5 (500 remove the zeros)
51 52 53 54(501 502 503 remove zeros) ......at last 996 997 998 999 1 (1000 remove 3 zeros).

> using java script and Html5...

Input number :

function  printNoZeros() {

```
var numbers = document.getElementById("number").value;
var output = "";

for (var i = 1; i <= numbers; i++) {
    var noZero = i.toString().replace(/0/g, '');
    console.log(noZero);
}
document.getElementById("anumbers").innerHTML = output;
```

}

but don't get it...it's remove zero.but not shown in balance numbers

ex input is 20
output like 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 2

Comment: Kindly provide your input, current output(not working) and expected output..

Comment: OP wants an input of `10` to return `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1` as in print all numbers with zeros stripped

Comment: In a text box i like to put 10 or 100 or 500 or 1000

Comment: output like mention the above text...

Comment: @Aziz, I could not see any efforts in posted question ;(

Comment: ya same like 500 1000 but shown every numbers shown from 1 and remove all zeros..

Comment: What's your question? What have you tried?

Comment: @Rfvgyhn  all wants cooked food but no one wants to cook it. Its was simple solution and if you just google it there are hundred od answers to this question. But he did not tried it seems.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove insignificant trailing zeros from a number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612744/remove-insignificant-trailing-zeros-from-a-number)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
function printNoZeros(n) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        var noZero = i.toString().replace(/0/g, '');
        console.log(noZero);
  }
}

printNoZeros(110);
```

This uses a global find & replace on the number, and removes all zeroes.
https://jsfiddle.net/19wLtwqh/1/

It currently prints them to the console, but it can be easily modified to print it somewhere else.

**How does it  work?**

It uses a simple [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for), then it converts the variable `i` to a string, and replaces the zeroes using a global [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Comment: That's the way to go. Not sure if OP wants them separate or in one outputted string tho.

Comment: @Aziz yeah he is not very specific, but hopefully that will guide him in the right direction.

Comment: @jerin You are welcome, and welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: how can find out the sum these number?

Comment: @jerin the sum before or after you remove the zeroes?

Comment: remove the zeros and find out the sum of numbers

Answer (score 1):

If you convert  var  to a string it will not display any trailing zeros, which aren't stored in the variable in the first place since it was created as a Number, not a String.

```
var a= 1.2000;

var b=a.toString()// 1.2
```

you can have a look at this [Remove insignificant trailing zeros from a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612744/remove-insignificant-trailing-zeros-from-a-number)

Comment: @HanletEscaño It works for decimals also. you can have a look at it .