# JQuery can't read exact total value

Tags: jquery

```
function totalrunningtime(){
        var sum = 0;
        var qty = document.getElementById("cutterprodqty").value;
            $(".cutterrumnoofmin").each(function() {
                                                                //add only if the value is number
            if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            }
            });
                                                            //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
            $("#cutterrunningtimetotal").html(sum);
            document.getElementById("cutterrunningtimetotal").value =  sum;

            var total = (sum/qty);
            var t = total.toFixed(3);
            $("#cutterspeed").val(t);


}
```

When i input on textfields 
ex.
420/600 the answer is 0.700, when I checked in calculator the answer is 0.7

Please help out, many thanks :)

Comment: Its because, you have used `.toFixed(3)`, use `.toFixed(1)`

Comment: `var t = total.toFixed(3).replace(/(\.[^0]*)0*/, '$1'/)`

Comment: I'm confused. Are you saying that 0.7 and 0.700 are not the same numeric value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove insignificant trailing zeros from a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612744/remove-insignificant-trailing-zeros-from-a-number)

Comment: @PrashantShirke problem with .toFixed(1) is (1/4).toFixed(1) will give you 0.3 which is probably not what the OP wants!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using [`Number#toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) it will automatically generate the 3 digits after the decimal part(`0.700` is equivalent to `0.7`).

To avoid the `0` at the trailing of decimal part use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method.

```
var t = total.toFixed(3).replace(/(\.[^0]*)0+/, function(_, m1){
   // check all are 0 or not 
   return m1.length > 1 ? m1 : '';
})
```

---

[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/iG6YgJ/1).

---

**UPDATE :** Or far better way by parsing the result string as *@JJJ*'s comment.

```
var t = Number(total.toFixed(3))
//  convert into string using toString() if necessary
```

Refer : [Remove insignificant trailing zeros from a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612744/remove-insignificant-trailing-zeros-from-a-number/19623253#19623253)

Comment: Not my downvote, but this doesn't work ("7" becomes "7.") and regex is overkill. (`var t = +total.toFixed(3);`)