# Javascript: Remove last decimal if zero

Tags: javascript

I have a list of numbers with 3 decimals. I need to remove the last decimal only if it's zero, *e.g.*

```
var x = 1.500 // I need 1.50
var y = 1.490 // I need 1.49
var z = 1.579 // I need 1.579
```

with

```
var x = 1.500
var noZeroes = x.toString() // I get "1.5", I need "1.50"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove insignificant trailing zeros from a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612744/remove-insignificant-trailing-zeros-from-a-number)

Comment: Not the same, I need to remove only last decimal

Comment: "I try ..." plz show your actual attempt to do this.

Comment: `toFixed` ought to give you something you can work with...

Comment: What about `2.999999999999` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check the last digit of a stringed number and remove the last zero, if exists.

```js
console.log([1.5, 1.49, 1.579].map(v => {
    var temp = v.toFixed(3);
    return temp.slice(-1) === '0'
        ? temp.slice(0, -1)
        : temp;
}));
```