# how avoid that the input type number delete the "0" final in a number

Tags: angular, angular6

This is my html code:

```
 <input type="number" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="home"  name="home" >
```

The problem is that I want to show the number in this way:

```
10.00
100.10
100.88
199.99
```

( I want a number with unlimited integer part and at least two digits)

With my code if there is this numbero 100.10 it show me 100.1. Anyone can help me?

Comment: You can use ngx-mask ref: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask

Comment: You can try and convert it into string as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3613112/7812112)

Comment: @SarthakAggarwal but after how I can do binding with the variable in .ts file, because this.home in ts component is number

Comment: @Doflamingo19 in your _.component.html_, use `{{home.toString()}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use parseFloat('151.8').toFixed(2);

Answer (score 0):

you should add an prop to the input tag like this

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="100" step="0.01"/>
```

that will be work.good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have :

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="home"  name="home" >

<p>{{home}}</p>
```

if you try using [DecimalPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe#parameters) of angular you'll get it:

```
{{home |  number:'1.1-1'}}
```

Comment: Selem I just try to use thuis solution but when modify the code it doesn't show the number in the input type number!

Comment: I need ot show the number in the input type number and not in the <p> </p> tags

Comment: your code is missing tho, please add that part of modifying and so @Doflamingo19

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your number to String which will trim the trailing zeros of your number

make the following changes in your **.html** file

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="home"  name="home" >
<p>{{home.toString()}}</p> <!-- converting into string -->
```