# Remove trailing zeros Intl.NumberFormat - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to remove the trailing zeros from the output when using Javascript `NumberFormat` to display Swedish currency?

I want output 200 kr instead 200,00 kr

Is there a built-in solution with `Intl.NumberFormat` to achieve this?

```js
console.log(Intl.NumberFormat('sv-SE', {style:'currency', currency: 'SEK'}).format(200));
```

Comment: Just don't use the Intl formatter ..?

Comment: No No No... I need Intl formating for a reason, for example the 'kr' in the end. So that option is out of the table.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat

Comment: Your response is a string, why don't you remove them from the string?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65172703/6919897

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use <s>`maximumSignificantDigits`</s> `maximumFractionDigits`. Something like:

```js
function getAmount(number) {
  if ((number | 0) < number) {
    return Intl.NumberFormat('sv-SE', {
      style: 'currency',
      currency: 'SEK'
    }).format(number)
  }
  return Intl.NumberFormat('sv-SE', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'SEK',
    maximumFractionDigits: 0
  }).format(number);
}

console.log(getAmount(200));
console.log(getAmount(200.23));
```

Comment: `maximumSignificantDigits` is used to drop whole part, not fraction

Comment: Way too complex.

Answer (score 0):

There is no build-in solution drop only zero fraction<strike>, but you can `.replace(/\.0+$/,'');`</strike> - it will not works for currency format, sorry.

To remove any fraction you can use `maximumFractionDigits` option of `Intl.NumberFormat()` constructor.

Comment: Show the OP an example.