# remove last zero after decimal in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

### Example

```
65.110 //result = 65.11
65.111 //result = 65.111
65.100 //result = 65.10
65.000 //result = 65.00
```

i tried the below one but it's not working

```
 round(3).replace(/(\.0+|0+)$/, '');
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove insignificant trailing zeros from a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612744/remove-insignificant-trailing-zeros-from-a-number)

Answer (score 1):

You could just replace the last zero, if exist.

```js
const
    format = number => number.toFixed(3).replace(/0$/, '');

console.log([65.110, 65.111, 65.100, 65.000].map(format));
```

Comment: getting error like map is not function

Comment: you need only the function `format`, maybe without arrows, like `function format(number) { return number.toFixed(3).replace(/0$/, ''); }`.