# javacript library to convert string into float

Tags: javascript, precision, negative-number, parsefloat

I'm working on a calculator app.
Everything is running fine but it runs into problem when I try to compute difference between to numbers with decimal.
The issue is coming from method I used to convert string into number.
e.g.
parseFloat("0.584") - parseFloat("0.94801")
-0.36401000000000006

Ideally the output should be -0.36401 but there unnecessary zeros with a 6 at the end.

As a temp fix I've used toFixed(5) in the end.
(parseFloat("0.584") - parseFloat("0.94801")).toFixed(5)
'-0.36401'
But that limits my calculator to be precise up to 5 decimal places

Is there a better way to convert strings into float with better precision?

Comment: No, you don't want to use float because float can not store decimals accurately no matter how you convert them. Find some decimal numbers library

Comment: Hi you can use Number like this  : const num1 = Number("0.584");

Comment: Using Number ends up with same problem Number("0.584") - Number("0.94801")
-0.36401000000000006

Comment: It's a common issue with float numbers and is not a Javascript matter only. Please follow this link may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612744/remove-insignificant-trailing-zeros-from-a-number. As far as I know there is no exact way to solve this issue but using round or toFixed (or set precision).